# rotate an image object along with the pointer in C

Tags: c++, c

I have a C application where i have loaded my image(gif) object onto the screen. Now i wish the Image object to rotate on one axis along with my pointer.

Means wherever i move the pointer on the screen, my image should rotate from a fixed point...How do i do that?

I have seen formulae like

```
newx = cos(angle) * oldx - sin(angle) * oldy

newy = sin(angle) * oldx + cos(angle) * oldy
```

but it inputs angle also..but i dont have the angles... i have pointer coordinates... **How do i make the object move according to the mouse pointer?**

Comment: Have you learn anything about trigonometry?

Comment: @Tani When you ask a question that gets answers that help you, you are supposed to *accept* the best answer by clicking the check mark on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously... You have learnt trigonometry in secondary school, right?

```
angle = arctan((pointerY - centerY) / (pointerX - centerX))
```

in C:

```
// obtain pointerX and pointerY; calculate centerX as width of the image / 2,
// centerY as heigth of the image / 2
double angle = atan2(pointerY - centerY, pointerX - centerX);

double newX = cos(angle) * oldX - sin(angle) * oldY
double newY = sin(angle) * oldX + cos(angle) * oldY
```

Comment: ya ofcourse... but i seem to have asked the wrong question or you understood it wrong... i am trying to rotate an object not a set of points... use some brains first and better respect the people.... this forum is meant to help people with questions and problems and not to show your damn attitudes...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that formula is perfectly fine if your rotation is in 2D space. You cannot remove angle from your formula because rotation without an angle is meaningless!! Think about it.

What you really need is to learn more basic stuff before doing what you are trying to do. For example, you should learn about:

- How to get the mouse location from your window management system (for example [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/))
- How to find an [angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) based on the mouse location
- How to draw quads with texture on them (For example using [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/))
- How to perform transformation, either [manually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) or for example using [OpenGL itself](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml)

#### Update

If you have no choice but to draw straight rectangles, you need to rotate the image manually, creating a new image. [This link](http://www.wavemetrics.com/products/igorpro/imageprocessing/imagetransforms/imagerotation.htm) contains all the keywords you need to lookup for doing that. However in short, it goes something like this:

```
for every point (dr,dc) in destination image
    find inverse transform of (dr,dc) in original image, named (or, oc)
    // Note that most probably or and oc are fractional numbers
    from the colors of:
        - (floor(or), floor(oc))
        - (floor(or), ceil(oc))
        - (ceil(or), floor(oc))
        - (ceil(or), ceil(oc))
    using bilinear interpolation, computing a color (r,g,b)
    dest_image[dr][dc] = (r,g,b)
```

Comment: thanks for replying.. i am confused about the transformation of the object about a point... i can draw my object on the screen but how to draw a slant object?

Comment: @Tani, how do you draw the object? Using what library?

Comment: functions used are actually private ones.. means i am using a different platform which is based on C ...so the functions n library used are different here...
Here Draw_Image function includes the coordinates and pointer to the base layer..where i have to draw...a pointer pointing to the object, and width and height..

Comment: You have three options: 1. find a way in your library to rotate images. 2. Find a way in your library to draw a quadrilateral with image as texture bound to it, then draw the quad rotated. 3. Generate a rotated image based on the angle. I will update the answer for option 3.

Comment: ohkkk that is almost like decoding every pixel of the image and assigning them to new coordinates....am i right?

Comment: That's exactly it. For simplicity, you can take the color of `(round(or), round(oc))` so you don't have much computations. This has bad quality though. There are more complex methods also that give better quality.

Comment: hmmmm i know...i have done that thing of extracting every pixel but i dont wish to implement that for a small game... will think of anything else...
anyways thanks for helping..pleasure talking with you :)

Comment: You should check your library for more details, there could be a rotation function somewhere. Also, you can upvote my answer if you had pleasure talking with me ;)

Answer (score 0):

the angle you calculate between where the user clicks on the screen and the old coordinates.

e.g.

on screen you have a square

```
( 0,10)-----(10,10)
       |    |
       |    |
       |    |
( 0, 0)-----(10, 0)
```

and if the user clicks in say (15,5)

you can *for example* calculate the angle relative your square from either a corner or from the cross section of the square then just use the formulas that you already have for each coordinate of the square.